# Apache, VirtualHost. How to block access by IP address on port 443?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, virtualhost, ip

The content of the 000-default.conf file at /etc/apache2/sites-available/ is the following:

```
VirtualHost 11.222.111.111:80>
    ServerName 11.222.111.111
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; preload"
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/000/public_html
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^11\.222\.111\.111
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://domain.tld/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

As you can see when someone access the IP it's redirects to a domain which is secured by SSL. However, I can't figure out how I can redirect **https://11.222.111.111** to the same website without crashing apache.

I have around 40 VirtualHost in separate .conf files. The above configuration redirects access by IP to the domain but when I use **https://11.222.111.111** I get **SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN**.

There is any way to remove **SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN** or to redicert **https:// 11.222.111.111** to the same website as I did with **http:// 11.222.111.111**?

Thank you.

Comment: I asking everyone NOT to vote down this question, if you write nothing to here. May, I have rights to get correct answer. If you don't know the answer, than don't vote.

Comment: downvote is not because of not knowing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAN indicates that your certificate is issued to a different domain. The certificate you use with the https connection has to be issued for the DNS name you use it with.
[It is said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095780/are-ssl-certificates-bound-to-the-servers-ip-address) that the certificate can contain an IP address, although it is better to have a DNS record for the server, especially for a public one. Have a certificate issued for the correct name, and the error will go away.

There are a few things to say though.

First, if you use self-signed certificates or your own CA, then the error won't really go away, unless you import the certificate on the client computer.

Second, your config seems to blindly redirect the connection to the https site, and for that, many of the directives can be simply left out. There is no reason to define a `DocumentRoot` or a `DirectoryIndex`, if the user never actually downloads anything from that VirtualHost. Also, the headers might better be defined in the https VirtualHost.